# How to encrypt url in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For example, I have the url in project: http://localhost:3000/images/20/thumb/300x300. Where 300x300 - dynamic params in url for crop width and height of image. How I can encrypt this url? May be by add the token for http header? I need this to protect the server from generates different urls with different width and height of image (100x100, 150x200, 300x200...) Show code example, please.

Comment: What do u mean by encrypting url?

Comment: Please more specific, why you want to encrypt url? What have you tried and what is your problem? Can you give us an example of encrypt url you want to achieve?

Comment: You might have an incorrect understanding of "encrypt"?

Comment: To protect server from generates different urls with different width and height of image (100x100, 250x250, 400x200...)

Comment: May be this https://github.com/attr-encrypted/encryptor helps!

Comment: 7 down votes, and no closing vote. Strange!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this at your route:

```
get 'images/:id/thumb/:size', size: /^[0-9]+x[0-9]+$/
```

and at your controller you can access id and size of the image like this:

```
def show
    @image= Image.find( params[:id] )
    width, height=params[:size].split("x").map{|s| s.to_i}
    # ...
end
```

If you have few fixed size of image that you accept then you can use constraints like following:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
 get 'images/:id/thumb/:size', size: /^[0-9]+x[0-9]+$/,
    constraints: ImageSizeConstraint.new
end

class ImageSizeConstraint
  def matches?(request)
    params = request.path_parameters

    if %w(100x100 150x200 300x200).include? params[:size]
        return true
    else
        return false
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: This functional already done. How to protect server from generates different :size in url?

Comment: Updated my answer, let me know if that helped.

Answer (score 0):

From your question I understand that you want server to render only one of accepted dimensions. So instead encrypt the URL, you can just filter it in your controller

```
...
ALLOW_THUMB_SIZES = %w( 100x100 150x200 300x200 )
...
def generate_image
  thumb_size = params[:thumb_size]
  if ALLOW_THUMB_SIZES.include? thumb_size
    # do resize image to thumb_size here
  else
    # resize to some default size e.g. 300x300
    # or throw exception...
  end
end
...
```

Comment: Why bother url from client side while you can process and filter it from server. Never trust anything from client :)